# Book featuring a robot, trolls, Merlin and Stonehenge

Tags: story-identification, books

I have been trying to locate a book that my brother read in the 90s.

All he can remember is it has a robot traveling to Stonehenge as well as Excalibur, Merlin and trolls.

Comment: Any idea what age group it was aimed for? Any recollection of the cover? Was it in English? Did it seem to be part of a series?

Comment: And, just to clarify, was the robot traveling to Stonehenge and traveling to see Excalibur, Merlin, and trolls, or were the latter joining to robot to visit Stonehenge?

Answer (score 11):

This sounds like the kids' book [*Sir MacHinery*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0695801678) where a wealthy hippy inventor type (American?) and his robot move to an old Scottish castle. A local crew of fairy creatures mistake the robot for a heralded knight (vague memories of a line about the fairies reading the robot's box like "MAC... HINERY. A fine Scottish name, although I've never heard of the clan." Arr arr arr.), and proceed to drag him and his owner into adventures in a magical reality where trolls present an existential threat to the world, and Excalibur and Merlin figure prominently. I read it over 30 years ago, so can't quite recall Stonehenge, but that sounds right in line. The book cover is below.

[image: Cover of book]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the one, he will be so happy! Can't express my gratitude enough!